# Trying to concatenate a form input using Liquid template in Shopify

Tags: templates, shopify, liquid

I don't know anything about Liquid, but I currently need to change an input in a form so that it appends a string to the input value.

The input is currently something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="customer[tags]" id="CustomerTag" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.tag' | t }}" {% if form.tag %}value="{{ form.tag }}"{% endif %} autofocus>
```

This input currently inserts the text inserted in the field into a customer tag, but I also need to concatenate it with some text so that the created tag has both the hardcoded string and the customer input.

I have tried this:

```
<input type="text" name="customer[tags]" id="CustomerTag" placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.tag' | t }}" {% if form.tag %}value="{{ "Automated Tag: " | append: form.tag }}"{% endif %} autofocus>
```

But it still stores just the form.tag input.

Thank you.

Comment: it would be better if you could break that one line code into a more readable format

Comment: I think you need to check and use JS code and try to modify the value of input text over `blur` or form on the `submit` event, otherwise, it doesn't work. liquid code runs either on page load. once you input and submit the form it doesn't work.

Comment: @Onkar You're right, I couldn't do it any other way, and it does make sense. You need to change client code in order for the data to be transformed on client input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would work:

```
{{ form.tag | prepend: 'Automated Tag: ' }}
```

(not tested)